# How: HTML table row click results in POST form linking to subsequent page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Evening all, I have the form, which is populated from a sql database.

```
    <table class="sortable"  border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <th> Serial Number </th>
        <th> Date </th>
        <th> Time </th>
        <th> Color </th>
        <th> Design </th>
        <th> Result </th>
    </tr>

<?php
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $num)
    {
        $serial = mysql_result($results, $i, 'serial_number');
        $date = mysql_result($results, $i, 'date');
        $time = mysql_result($results, $i, 'time');
        $airport = mysql_result($results, $i, 'color');
        $terminal = mysql_result($results, $i, 'design');
        $result = mysql_result($results, $i, 'result');

?>

    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $serial; ?> </a></td>
        <td> <?php echo $date; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $time; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $color; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $design; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $result; ?> </td>
    </tr>

<?php
    $i++;
    }

?>
```

What I would like to do is have each row of the table clickable. When each row is clicked, one cell of data from that row (the first cell) is sent via (POST) to the next page. Can a form be integrated into each tr??

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a GET request?

Comment: A GET request is fine, is it easier that way? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with that code in echo when create your table:

```
<td><?php echo('<a href="my_page.php?action&serial='.$serial.'">'.$serial.'</a>');?></td>
```

For each data that you have!

OTHER SOLUTION WITHOUT ACTION

```
<td><?php echo('<a href="my_page.php?serial='.$serial.'">'.$serial.'</a>');?></td>
```

`my_page.php` - **where to send the data**

`?[variable_name]` - **where is stored the data**

Comment: I've just had to go out for about 30 mins, I'll have a crack once I get back. Thanks so much for all the help.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

You specify jQuery in your tags, so I assume you can use that.

```
// when any row is clicked
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
  // get the value
  var value = $(this).find('td:first').text();
  // redirect the user with the value as a GET variable
  window.location = nextPage + '?data=' + value;
});
```

Where `nextPage` is the URL of the page you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: yes, a form can be integrated into each tr.

The long answer - use just as you did before:

```
<tr>
    <td> 
      <form method="post" target="details.php">
          <input type="submit" name="more" value="<?php echo $serial; ?>"
      </form>
      <?php echo $serial; ?>
    </td>
    <td> <?php echo $date; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $time; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $color; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $design; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $result; ?> </td>
</tr>
```

But GET is easier, make a series of links that go details.php?number=123, or whichever:

```
    <td> 
      <a href="details.php?number=<?php echo $serial; ?>"
      <?php echo $serial; ?>
      </a>
    </td>
```

Although get can use a form, the data send is not user-customised, so the form data can be generated to use like a link.